# jQuery trigger click infinitely

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, carousel, autoscroll

I have made a simple jQuery slider with next and previous buttons to move slides. I want to now enable it to autoscroll when buttons aren't manually pressed. I then want it to stop scrolling when someone hovers over the slide and start again when they are not hovering over it.

I have used this code here, but it only scrolls the first slide, it won't continue to do it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#next').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
}
```

How can I make this continually slide, but also how can I make it stop when hovering over a slide?

My html markup is this:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a id="prev" onclick="prev()"></a>Prev</li>
    <li><a id="next" onclick="next()"></a>Next</li>
</ul>
<div id="viewport">
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Script can also be seen in use here:
http://www.samskirrow.com/projects/carousel

Now I'm using this jQuery code. Slider changes byitself and stops on hover....but it won't start on page load. What changes do I need to make??

```
jQuery('#viewport').hover(function() {
window.clearInterval(timer);    
}, function() {
timer = window.setInterval(function(){ jQuery('#next').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function, which gives you a timer instance. Then you can call the [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) function, whenever you need to stop the triggering (i.e. during the hover).

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){...}, 1000); //whenever you need the periodical call
...
...
clearInterval(timer); //whenever you want to clear it
```

In your case you can define three functions and one variable:

```
var timer = null;
var triggerFunc = function(){ jQuery('#next').trigger('click');};
var periodicFunc = function() {timer = window.setInterval(triggerFunc , 1000);};
var clearFunc = function() {window.clearInterval(timer);};
```

Then your logic would become very simple:

```
jQuery('#viewport').hover(clearFunc ,periodicFunc);
periodicFunc();
```

Notice the initial call `periodFunc();`.

Comment: what syntax would I use for the clearInterval bit? Got the setInterval working fine

Comment: check my last edit: you simply call `clearInterval(timer);` with the same var you used for `setInterval`.

Comment: Almost there - slider doesn't start by sliding though, I have to hover over it to get it to start. See revised code above

Comment: yes, because you should initially call the setInterval function: see my last edit for a better functional design.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the same syntax pretty much.

**with timeout :**

```
timeoutvariable = setTimeout(function(){},1000);
clearTimeout(timeoutvariable);
```

**with interval**

```
intervalvariable = setTimeout(function(){},1000);
clearInterval(intervalvariable);
```

With that said however, I would suggest coding your behavior for the slider in manner where the html element is more decoupled from the behavior.

Instead of triggering the click event so often, simply call `next()` directly from inside the interval. This allows you to use this next functionality through things other than button, instead of always depending on the button being there. (more reusable code)